# Firebase: Add child to database if there is none?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my Firebase database, I want to check if a child exists in `[[My firebase]]/users` with the same `Uid` as the `Uid` of the person currently logged in.

Here is the code:

```
// Initialize FirebaseAuth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        //Get firebase database
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        //Set a SINGLE value listener & check if user exists in data base.
        final DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("users");
        ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                //If user does not exists in data base, create user and add to database.
                if(!dataSnapshot.hasChild(mFirebaseUser.getUid())){
                    ref.child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(new User("Random Nick"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //Not implemented yet
            }
        });
```

I only want to check it once (when person logs in/registers). When I run the code, nothing appears in the Firebase db.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is, but do note what you're doing here.  You're fetching *all* the data for *all* the users just to see if *one* might exist.  That seems excessive.

Comment: @DougStevenson If a child with the Uid does not exists, it does not get added as a child. That's what I want to happen. And do you have a suggestion on the fetching issue? Should I use "user/mFirebaseUser.getUid()" as path and see if snapshot.exists()?

Comment: @DougStevenson Also I have set in the rules that you can only access your own data, read&write for /users is set to "$uid == auth.uid"

Comment: The user ids are always different, it will never exist one that is the same

Comment: user id will unique for every registeration and also if you register with email and password,unique email is allowed otherwise it will throws an exception.

Comment: @MartinDeSimone I know, I am checking if "it's the first time a user logs in" by checking if they are added to the user list. If they are not, I create a child with their user id in my database under users, and add other info under their uid.

Comment: How are users going to login if they dont have te information in the db

Comment: @MartinDeSimone it is a separate database from the auth database, it's a custom one I build in my real-time database part. But I solved my problem, the code was working it was just a line of code was placed in the wrong part of class :) Thanks for your input Martin!